# Custom Constraints for worker manager

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-workmanager

I have a use case that my worker should work only when my bluetooth device is connected with my android application.
How can i set custom constraints in work manager in order to run my worker class.

**Example**
My application should sync my ble device data with server ONLY when internet is connected AND my BLE device is connected with my application.

I know that internet constraint is available in WorkManager BUT custom constraint that is in my case BLE device should connected need to handle in my scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by custom constraints ? May be you should put some example of such custom constraints..

Comment: @SantanuSur Added Example in my question. Thanks

Comment: Just make a check ..before enqueueing the working.. only if its connected start the work ..

Comment: I want to enqueue that tasks by adding these constraints at the start of app. Then whenever that constraints meet that worker should execute.

Comment: I can see the need for this. My use case is an "authenticated" constraint. My app can work offline but to access the APIs it needs to have a valid access token. The app can work without it but cannot sync without it. It would be great to have an authenticated constraint.

Answer (score 5):

WorkManager doesn't supports custom constraints.

You can open a feature request on the [WorkManager issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197) with some additional details.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature, but what you could do is:

- Use the internet constraint
- Once the worker starts, check if your device is connected to the required Bluetooth device
- If yes -> execute your code
- If not -> End the worker

If you need to do it periodically, you can use the `PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder`